# What does CSS property 'strong' define?

Tags: html, css

Like this:

```
strong {
    font-style: italic;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

In exactly which area will it work?

Comment: 3 seconds of googling: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_strong.asp – If that doesn’t answer your question, rephrase it to make clear what exactly you want.

Answer (score 2):

That will target the `<strong>` element, giving it italics and forcing all text to uppercase.  Not recommended as either the `<i>` or `<em>` tags are more semantically-correct.

Comment: What’s the semantics of the `<i>` element? I’d on the contrary say that `<strong>` is the better choice since it, just like `<em>` marks emphasis, whereas `<i>` just prints text in italics. Likewise there is no semantics to `<b>`. It just means “print in bold.”

Comment: From https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/i - "In earlier versions of the HTML spec, `<i>` was merely a presentational element used to display text in italics, much like the `<b>` tag was used to display text in bold letters. This is no longer true, as these tags now define semantics rather than typographic appearance. `<i>` should represent a range of text with a different semantic meaning whose typical typographic representation is italicized. This means a browser will typically still display its contents in italic type, but is, by definition, no longer required to."

Comment: A good example of how the expected behaviour has changed is how FontAwesome (http://fontawesome.io/examples/) now uses `<i>` as an icon wrapper - not something you'd typically want italicised.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It seems like the resource with which I learned CSS is outdated. According to the W3C, “The `<i>` element represents a span of text in an alternate voice or mood, or otherwise offset from the normal prose in a manner indicating a different quality of text, such as a taxonomic designation, a technical term, an idiomatic phrase from another language, transliteration, a thought, or a ship name in Western texts.” [https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/textlevel-semantics.html#the-i-element]

Comment: It is impossible to say element X is "more semantically correct" than element Y without knowing what content it is representing.

Comment: @bleistift2 - The use of the `<i>` element remains a matter of much debate, as to whether the current element definition can be stretched to cover the use of it as an icon wrapper, whether the definition should be changed to cover this now common usage, or whether the usage should remain non-conforming to the standard.

Answer (score 1):

It work for html tag.

```
<strong></strong>
```

This tag is similar to bold html tag.

```
<b></b>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

The `<strong>` tag is a phrase tag. It defines `important` text. - [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_strong.asp)

`strong {
font-style: italic;
text-transform: uppercase;
}`

Will target all `<strong></strong>` elements content in it's target `<html>` page and `italice` the text content and also make the text content `uppercase`

This means everytime you use the `<strong>` tag it'll have these extra effects.